# Integral of a function mapping an element to a measure of a set

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

A really strange question here in my opinion:

> Let $A,B$ be two measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}^1$. Define $f(x) = |(A-x) \cap B|$. Evaluate $\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}fdx$. Here $|\cdot|$ refers to the measure.

Here $f$ is clearly non-negative, so I tried using the definition of Lebesgue integral: $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}fdx = \sup\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^1}sdx:0\leq s\leq f\right\},$$
where $s$ are simple functions. But I realised that I couldn't come up with any simple functions.

I tried breaking up $\mathbb{R}^1$ into two parts:
$$E_1 =\{y \in \mathbb{R}^1: y \in A \cap B\},E_2 = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^1: y \notin A \cap B\}$$
and then considering the sum
$$\int_{E_1}fdx+\int_{E_2}fdx$$
and then I'm clueless as to how to proceed. I'm guessing the answer should be something intuitive like $|A \cap B|$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What does $|\cdot|$ mean? Is it the cardinality?

Comment: It refers to the (Lebesgue) measure, I'll state it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One could proceed as follows. Note that we can rewrite $f(x)=|(A-x)\cap B|=\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{B}(y)1_A(x+y)dy$. Then the question becomes evaluating the expression
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{B}(y)1_A(x+y)dydx.$$
By translation invariance of the Lesbeque measure on $\mathbb{R}$, it follows that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{B}(y)1_A(x+y)dydx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_{B}(y)1_A(y)dydx=\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_B(y)dy\int_{\mathbb{R}}1_A(x)dx=|A|\cdot |B|.$$

Comment: So $A -x$ refers to translating the elements of $A$ by $-x$? I thought it was removing $x$ from $A$. Wow that's such a big misinterpretation.

Comment: Oh yes that is how I interpreted it, now that I think of it I am not quite sure how to interpret it, maybe you can look how it is defined in your source.

Comment: I guess you're right, because otherwise it doesn't really affect the measure by just removing a point $x$.